# Oracle Primavera P6 8.3 password hash

Tags: hash, sha256, password-encryption, primavera

I am facing the problem of generate the same SHA256 hash of the password as stored in primavera's database in users table.
Every sha256 hash generator I found make the same SHA256 hashes between them but different from priavera's one!
I need to integrate our custom application with primavera so I want to use primavera's users/password to make authentication of the users. Theoretically I need to get user's password, calculate the sha256 hash and compare it with the primavera's hash.
But as I can see there is not really SHA256 hash or primavera uses some password salt stuff.
Is any body know, how exactly primavera calculates password hashes?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a straight sha256 hash - that would be too easy. P6 can authenticate through other mechanisms as well as their native one and could change their algorithm whenever they want.

I would advise authenticating to P6 through either the P6 java api or web services. This will protect you against Primavera changes to their authentication algorithms, decouple you from changes to how your company authenticates with P6 (e.g. native or AD/LDAP) and also allow you to delegate p6 access to p6 rather than working that out as well.

Bottom line - if you want to integrate your custom application with P6 then use the P6 integration apis.